# How to Sort Date in descending order From Arraylist Date in android?

Tags: java, android, date, arraylist, sortedlist

I have an `ArrayList` which stores `Date`s and I sorted them in descending order. Now I want to display them in a `ListView`. This is what I did so far:

```
 spndata.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {

                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    list = DBAdpter.requestUserData(assosiatetoken);
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                        if (list.get(i).lastModifiedDate != null) {
                            lv.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(
                                    getApplicationContext(), list));
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    list = DBAdpter.requestUserData(assosiatetoken);

                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    SimpleDateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");    
                    String formattedDate3 = df3.format(c.getTime());                        
                    Log.v("log_tag", "Date  " + formattedDate3);

                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {                         
                        if (list.get(i).submitDate != null) {                               
                            String sDate = list.get(i).submitDate;                              
                            SimpleDateFormat df4 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");    
                            String formattedDate4 = df4.format(sDate);

                            Map<Date, Integer> dateMap = new TreeMap<Date, Integer>(new Comparator<Date>(){  
                                 public int compare(Date formattedDate3, Date formattedDate4) {
                                     return formattedDate3.compareTo(formattedDate4);
                                 }
                            });
                            lv.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(
                                    getApplicationContext(), list));
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:

                    break;

                case 3:

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }

        });
```

Comment: For new readers consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Create `Arraylist<Date>` of Date class. And use `Collections.sort()` for ascending order.

See [sort(List<T> list)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-)

> Sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the natural ordering of its elements.

For Sort it in descending order See [Collections.reverseOrder()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder--)

```
Collections.sort(yourList, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Answer (score 21):

Just add like this in case 1: like this

```
 case 0:
     list = DBAdpter.requestUserData(assosiatetoken);
     Collections.sort(list, byDate);
     for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
         if (list.get(i).lastModifiedDate != null) {
             lv.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(
                     getApplicationContext(), list));
         }
     }
     break;
```

and put this method at end of the your class

```
static final Comparator<All_Request_data_dto> byDate = new Comparator<All_Request_data_dto>() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");

    public int compare(All_Request_data_dto ord1, All_Request_data_dto ord2) {
        Date d1 = null;
        Date d2 = null;
        try {
            d1 = sdf.parse(ord1.lastModifiedDate);
            d2 = sdf.parse(ord2.lastModifiedDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime() ? -1 : 1);     //descending
    //  return (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime() ? 1 : -1);     //ascending
    }
};
```

Comment: import these packages  import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;

Comment: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<All_Request_data_dto>).

Comment: The inferred type All_Request_data_dto is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>

Comment: please wait  1    min please put your DTO class here

Comment: public class All_Request_data_dto {
 String requestId;
 String projectId;
 String tableId;
 String projectName;
 String displayId;
 String issueId;
 String title;
 String state;
 String lastModifiedDate;
 String lastModifier;
 String lastStateChanger;
 String owner;
 String submitDate;
 String submitter;
 String sort_submit_date;
}

Comment: this is the core line only      return (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime() ? -1 : 1);

Answer (score 17):

Date's compareTo() you're using will work for ascending order.

To do descending, just reverse the value of compareTo() coming out. You can use a single Comparator class that takes in a flag/enum in the constructor that identifies the sort order

```
public int compare(MyObject lhs, MyObject rhs) {

    if(SortDirection.Ascending == m_sortDirection) {
        return lhs.MyDateTime.compareTo(rhs.MyDateTime);
    }

    return rhs.MyDateTime.compareTo(lhs.MyDateTime);
}
```

You need to call [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to actually sort the list.

As a side note, I'm not sure why you're defining your map inside your for loop. I'm not exactly sure what your code is trying to do, but I assume you want to populate the indexed values from your for loop in to the map.

Comment: The "!" way will not work, since compareTo returns an int, to reverse the value, either you change the order of the objects, or use: Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder(comparator));

Comment: @ricvieira excellent point! I have modified my answer to include reversing the order in the compare() method

Answer (score 11):

If date in string format convert it to date format for each object :

```
String argmodifiledDate = "2014-04-06 22:26:15";
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");  
            try
            {
                this.modifiledDate = format.parse(argmodifiledDate);
            }
            catch (ParseException e)
            {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Then sort the arraylist in descending order :

```
ArrayList<Document> lstDocument= this.objDocument.getArlstDocuments();
        Collections.sort(lstDocument, new Comparator<Document>() {
              public int compare(Document o1, Document o2) {
                  if (o1.getModifiledDate() == null || o2.getModifiledDate() == null)
                    return 0;     
                  return o2.getModifiledDate().compareTo(o1.getModifiledDate());
              }
            });
```

Answer (score 4):

[`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) so just create list of `List<Date>` and sort it using `Collections.sort()`. And use [`Collections.reverseOrder()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28java.util.Comparator%29) to get comparator in `reverse ordering`.

From Java Doc

> Returns a comparator that imposes the reverse ordering of the specified comparator. If the specified comparator is null, this method is equivalent to reverseOrder() (in other words, it returns a comparator that imposes the reverse of the natural ordering on a collection of objects that implement the Comparable interface).

Answer (score 4):

Easier alternative to above answers

1. If Object(Model Class/POJO) contains the **date in String** datatype.

   ```
   private void sortArray(ArrayList<myObject> arraylist) {
   SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"); //your own date format
   if (reports != null) {
       Collections.sort(arraylist, new Comparator<myObject>() {
           @Override
           public int compare(myObject o1, myObject o2) {
               try {
                   return simpleDateFormat.parse(o2.getCreated_at()).compareTo(simpleDateFormat.parse(o1.getCreated_at()));
               } catch (ParseException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   return 0;
               }
           }
       });
   }
   ```
2. If Object(Model Class/POJO) contains **date in Date** datatype

   ```
   private void sortArray(ArrayList<myObject> arrayList) {
   if (arrayList != null) {
       Collections.sort(arrayList, new Comparator<myObject>() {
           @Override
           public int compare(myObject o1, myObject o2) {
               return o2.getCreated_at().compareTo(o1.getCreated_at()); }
       });
   } }
   ```

The above code is for sorting the array in **descending order** of date,
swap o1 and o2 for **ascending order**.