# How to Sort an Arraylist of Date in ascending and descending order which is in String format

Tags: java, android

I have arrayLists of Dates which is in String format then how can I sort this arraylists,

```
ArrayList<String> aryBeginDate;
ArrayList<String> aryDueDate;

for (int i = 0; i < arySubject.size(); i++) {

    RowItem row = new RowItem();
    row.setSubject(arySubject.get(i).toString());
    row.setUser(aryFromUser.get(i).toString());

    if (aryBeginDate.equals(" ")) {
        row.setStartDate(" ");
    } else {
        row.setStartDate(aryBeginDate.get(i).toString()); \\Have to sort at this line
    }

    if (aryDueDate.equals(" ")) {
        row.setEndDate(" ");
    } else {
        row.setEndDate(aryDueDate.get(i).toString()); \\Have to sort at this line
    }

    aryListBean.add(row);

}
```

Comment: And why aren't you having an `ArrayList<Date>` itself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120316/how-to-sort-date-in-descending-order-from-arraylist-date-in-android?rq=1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use a String when you want a Date. Use a Date. You should only transfom the Date to a String when displaying it. Otherwise, everywhere in the code, the date should of type Date. This is what allows sorting in chronological order, because dates have a natural order which is chronological.

So, once the `RowItem` has a `startDate` and an `endDate`, both being of type `Date`, you can sort a list of row items by start date using a simple comparator:

```
Collections.sort(rowItems, new Comparator<RowItem>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(RowItem r1, RowItem 2) {
        return r1.getStartDate().compareTo(r2.getStartDate());
    }
});
```

Also, fix your indentationof if/else blocks, because your way is really not readable:

```
if (aryBeginDate.equals(" ")) {
    row.setStartDate(" ");
} 
else {
    row.setStartDate(aryBeginDate.get(i).toString());
}
```

Comment: Hello... and what should we do If two dates are same :)

Comment: Then the compareTo method will return 0, and the order of these two row items is undefined. If you want it defined, then compare the two objects based on another criterion if the first comparison returns 0.

Comment: What if I what the latest date first ?

Comment: @Chetu you would use `r2.getStartDate().compareTo(r1.getStartDate())`, or `-r1.getStartDate().compareTo(r2.getStartDate())`.

Comment: _As a side note_: it would be better to also check if any of the dates is `null`, otherwise one can easily get _NPE_.

Answer (score 4):

Very Simple Answer:For Ascending just call this method:

```
Collections.sort(mArrayList, new OutcomeAscComparator());
public class OutcomeAscComparator implements Comparator<Select>
    {
        public int compare(Select left, Select right) {
            return left.getOutcome().compareTo(right.getOutcome());
        }
    }
```

Select is my model, For Descending:

```
Collections.sort(mArrayList, new OutcomeDescComparator());
public class OutcomeDescComparator implements Comparator<Select>
    {
        public int compare(Select left, Select right) {
            return right.getOutcome().compareTo(left.getOutcome());
        }
    }
```

Please dont forget to refresh your list view IF you want your list to be AScending and Descending

```
                mListView.invalidateViews();

                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be very painful if you try to sort this yourself with Strings. I'd recommend you to parse the String to a Date (check JodaTime for a very convenient Date/Time tool) and then sort with java.util.Collections.sort().

Comment: I am already feeling pain :) I have to change so much things to parse String to Date..plz Help me..I have stuck in my Project

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Comparator` to sort the list. Something like this:

```
Collections.sort(aryListBean, new Comparator<RowItem>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(RowItem r1, RowItem r2) {
        // Place your compare logic here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an in built function on ArrayList `sort()`. Since you are using String, this will work.

Comment: But it'll just sort the Strings per Alphabet, not the Dates, and I guess he wants to sort the dates.

Comment: Numbers are also considered in the same way as strings. 1 will always come before 2 when you sort them as strings.

Comment: can you give me an example plz??

Comment: First comment `Collections.sort(arr);` and run, then uncomment and run. You will see the difference:`public static void main(String[] args) {
   ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>();
   arr.add("12-12-12");
   arr.add("11-12-12");
   arr.add("09-12-12");
   Collections.sort(arr);
   System.out.println(arr);
 }`

Answer (score 0):

First convert the String in Date and create the arraylist. Then use the Collection sort method for sorting the arraylist.