# Sorting an ArrayList?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I am trying to make a function, that allows you to `sort` the dates in descending or ascending order. However, I'm not too sure how I should go about this. This is what I've worked out so far, but got completely stuck:

```
public void sortByYear() {
   String askID = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Would you like to sort by ascending or descending?");
   if(askID.equalsIgnoreCase("ascending")){
      for(String datePersons : personList){
         String[] splitPerson = datePersons.split("_");
         String date = splitPerson[5];   
      }
   } else if(askID.equalsIgnoreCase("descending")){

     }
}
```

The format that my `ArrayList` works with, is  this: `ID_NAME_MAIL_PHONE_CITY_DATETIME#`

Which in the `ArrayList`, with data in it, looks like this:

```
7_Geoffrey Wolf_fermentum.risus@malesuadaaugue.net_1-382-295-5799_Warwick_2010-03-27 09:47:41
```

If I got 99 different persons with different dates, how would I be able to sort them? I used this part to split and find the dates:

```
String[] splitPerson = datePersons.split("_");
String date = splitPerson[5];
```

Best Regards.

Comment: Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085608/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-of-date-in-ascending-and-descending-order-which-is-in-s

Comment: Is that real user data in your example `dataPersons`?? :-O

Comment: Made up userdata from my teacher. He gave us 99 lines of userdata to work with, however, I've been stuck at this last question for the past 3 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Arrays.sort` method and use a custom comparator. In the comparator implementation, parse the date string, construct date object and compare them.

i.e.

```
Arrays.sort(personList, new Comparator<String>() {
   public int compare(String person1, String person2) {
       Date date1 = parseDate(person1);
       Date date2 = parseDate(person2);
       return date1.compareTo(date2);
       //return date2.compareTo(date1) for reverse order
   } 
});
```

If `personList` is a List/Collection and not an array, use sort method in `Collections` class which works similar to the `Arrays.sort` method.

Comment: Sorry if this might be too simple to ask, but where does date1 and date2 come from? Would this automatically run through all the 99 lines of persons, instead of just 2?

Comment: You have to implement the parseDate method. Yes it will run as many comparisons as is needed to correctly sort your list or array. The parseDate method will look something like:
<code>
    private Date parseDate(String person) {
        String[] splitPerson = person.split("_");
        String date = splitPerson[5];
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(date);
    }
</code>

Answer (score 0):

First, parse the date string into a proper `java.util.Date` object using e.g. a `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` (assuming your dates are consistently formatted). Then you can sort the list of `Date` using either the natural ordering or the reverse ordering, depending on the value of `askID`.

Note that there is no need to write a custom comparator since a reverse comparator comes out of the box: `java.util.Collections.reverseOrder()`. The following is an example snippet:

```
public static void sortByYear() throws ParseException {
    // ...
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
    List<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String date : personList) {
        Date parsedDate = format.parse(date);
        dateList.add(parsedDate);
    }
    if (askID.equalsIgnoreCase("ascending")) {
        Collections.sort(dateList);
    } else {
        Collections.sort(dateList, Collections.reverseOrder());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The object-oriented solution to the problem would be to create a model class, `Person`, for holding the different attributes that are currently concatenated into a single string. You could then have `Person` implement the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, e.g. like this:

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>{

    private Date dateTime;

    /*
    * Clip other fields, constructor and accessor methods.
    */

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person other) {
        return this.dateTime.compareTo(other.dateTime);
    }
}
```

Now that the ordering of a `Person` would be defined based on the `dateTime` attribute, sorting a `List<Person> myPersonList` in ascending datetime order is as simple as [`Collections.sort(myPersonList)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) and sorting by descending order as simple as `Collections.sort(myPersonList, Collections.reverseOrder())`.

Alternatively, the quick-and-dirty solution to the problem is to create a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), which would allow you to order a list of `List<String> myStringList` based on the datetime token (in index `5`, when split by the `_` delimiter) of each element:

```
public class UserInfoDateTimeComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    // see docs for correct format:
    // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
    private static final DateFormat DATETIME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(...)

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {

        // guards for null parameters
        if (s1 == null) {
            return s2 == null ? 0 : -1;
        } else if (s2 == null) {
            return 1;
        }

        try {
            Date dateTime1 = DATETIME_FORMAT.parse(s1.split("_")[5]);
            Date dateTime2 = DATETIME_FORMAT.parse(s2.split("_")[5]);
            return dateTime1.compareTo(dateTime2);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

With `Comparator<String> myComparator = new UserInfoDateTimeComparator()`, `myStringList` can be sorted through [`Collections.sort(myStringList, myComparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) in ascending datetime order and through `Collections.sort(myStringList, Collections.reverseOrder(myComparator))` in descending order.